# ifort ld: library not found for -lgcc_s

Tags: macos, fortran

How to resolve this problem: when I compile my `Fortran` code using `ifort` ?

```
ifort -o hello hello.f90 
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s
```

And it worked well before I updated my Mac OS 10.9 to 10.10.

Comment: Have you set up the environment for the compiler? With `ifort` you need to source `compilervars.sh`, e.g. `. ${HOME}/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I did that, but it still didn't work. And I suspect that this problem caused by updating Mac OS to 10.10, maybe some library missed or miss linked.

Comment: you might try reinatalling / upgrading Xcode and then ifort in case the upgrade is the problem.